# Create folders and subfolders from list with 1 file in each

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, mkdir

I have a dataframe like this:

```
mgr1       mgr2      mgr3
abc        def       fed
asd        dij       
sdf
```

the df does contain nulls

I am trying to make a directory where the unique `mgr3` value(s) is the name of the top level folder, `mgr2` unique value(s) are sub folders, `mgr1` unique value(s) are folders within the second sub folder etc. And then add just one txt file in each folder.

I went a route of turning each column into a variable with the unique strings, and then trying to do some for loop that creates a folder based on those strings, but i've not been successful.

```
#someting like this
mgr1 = list(set(df.mgr1))
mgr1 = [x for x in mgr1 if str(x) != 'nan']
mgr1 = ''.join(mgr1)
# print(mgr1)

for i in mgr1:
    os.system ("mkdir "+i)
    for j in range (1):
            os.system ("touch "+str(i)+"/"+str(j)+".txt")
```

any ideas?

Attempt 1:

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.read_csv('sas-user-mappings-to-ceo.csv')

eight = df.loc[~df['mgr8'].isnull(), 'mgr8'].tolist()
seven = df.loc[~df['mgr7'].isnull(), 'mgr7'].tolist()
six = df.loc[~df['mgr6'].isnull(), 'mgr6'].tolist()
five = df.loc[~df['mgr5'].isnull(), 'mgr5'].tolist()
four = df.loc[~df['mgr4'].isnull(), 'mgr4'].tolist()
three = df.loc[~df['mgr3'].isnull(), 'mgr3'].tolist()
two = df.loc[~df['mgr2'].isnull(), 'mgr2'].tolist()
one = df.loc[~df['mgr1'].isnull(), 'mgr1'].tolist()
user_name = df.loc[~df['user_name'].isnull(), 'user_name'].tolist()
# third = df.loc[~df['user_lid'].isnull(), 'user_lid'].tolist()

paths = [list(x) for x in itertools.product(eight, seven, six, five, four, three, two, one, user_name)]

for pathToWrite in paths:
    pathToWrite = "\Users\max\Downloads\users_visual"
    toCreate = os.path.join("C:", pathToWrite)

    os.mkdir(toCreate)

error: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

base = df.loc[~df['mgr3'].isnull(), 'mgr3'].tolist()
sec = df.loc[~df['mgr2'].isnull(), 'mgr2'].tolist()
third = df.loc[~df['mgr1'].isnull(), 'mgr1'].tolist()

paths = [list(x) for x in itertools.product(base, sec, third)]

for pathToWrite in paths:
    #change the path to where ever you need to
    toCreate = os.path.join("C:", *pathToWrite)

    os.mkdir(toCreate)
```

Get all the paths in separate lists. Since I didn't know if your colunmns were ordered I just did it on separate lines. Use itertools to create all the paths, then loop over the list of paths and make it.

Comment: i just added my attempt to the post. Not sure what i'm doing wrong?!

Comment: Try changing `df = pd.read_csv('sas-user-mappings-to-ceo.csv')` to `df = pd.read_csv('sas-user-mappings-to-ceo.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')` Its an issue with reading the actual csv. If this doens't work you will have to try another encoding.

Comment: Also make sure you don't overwrite 'pathToWrite'  in the for loop when you make all the dirs.

Comment: ok good call. i added latin1 and then set() around each of the lists. need them to be unique lists. but when i run the paths line - i get an error: `MemoryError`. I the df shape is 1219, 10. is this too big ?

Comment: if you wanted them to be unique, change `tolist()` to `.unique().tolist()`, dont change it to a set.

Comment: man - i tried adding .unique() to the end but it didn't work. still getting the memory error though.